# RecyclerView Array list using two array list

Tags: android, string, android-recyclerview

I am new to android Developing i learned how to create a RecyclerView list using custom adapters.I created a Separate method to add movies and then use my class in my on create method and it worked fine for me.

```
{
//Separate class for my constructor and here Movie is my getter and setter class.

 private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("movie name ","year","details");

//what if i want that if user add the data which user has entered 

        movieList.add(movie);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

//Adapter class
private List moviesList;

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
```

//main Activity class
//oncreate method

```
    text = findViewById(R.id.edit_1);
    text1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_2);
    text2 = findViewById(R.id.edit_3);

    textS = text.getText().toString().trim();
    textS1 = text1.getText().toString().trim();
    textS2 = text2.getText().toString().trim();



    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // vertical RecyclerView
    // keep movie_list_row.xml width to `match_parent`
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

    // horizontal RecyclerView
    // keep movie_list_row.xml width to `wrap_content`
    // RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // adding inbuilt divider line
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    // adding custom divider line with padding 16dp
    // recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 16));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // row click listener
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            prepareMovieData();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Prepares sample data to provide data set to adapter
 */
private void prepareMovieData() {

    Movie newdata = new Movie("Texts","working","1234");
    movieList.add(newdata);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // so that it will render the list with new data
}
```

After that i try to update the code with 3 edit texts,one button, and recyclerview i was trying to store all 3 edit text values in string and then try to a show my string values in the place of "movie name" but i am not able to add string name as it can't be in double quotes.

Then i tried to make a array list and pass the array list in 
Movie movie = new Movie (array list)

I want that instead of showing manually how can i store my string values or edit text to the custom view i created and in list form like recyclerView.

Please help me out what method can i try stucked on this from last 3 days.

Comment: Can Any one Please Answer to My problem?

Comment: show us all code related to your task . it is hard to understand your question.?

Comment: try to a show my string values in the place of "movie name" but i am not able to add string name as it can't be in double quotes. --- What do you mean by this line?

Comment: r u asking that you want to create 3 edittext and a button. The values that you will enter in the editText and then click on the button, those values will be displayed on the recyclerView layout?? is that your need?

Comment: yes sir. I successful created the project but its not showing values of edit text instead show blank if i pass the String values to the model class.

Comment: @Sunny please update the question with your code , `activity or fragment`, `xml`, `adapter` . Otherwise how we can know where is the error.?

Comment: sir updated the code.

Comment: @sajith sir i have updated the code please help me out